Is this Hadith authentic about the virgins of paradise
Abu Hurayra said, Allah be well-pleased with him: The Messenger of Allah said, upon him blessings and peace: “The humblest of the People of Paradise in rank shall have seven levels and as he will be on the sixth, below the seventh, he will have three hundred servants, every morning and evening three hundred dishes of gold shall be brought before him, every dish carrying something the other does not. He will taste pleasure as sharply with the first dish as he will with the last. He shall say, ‘My Lord! If you gave me permission, I would feed all the people of Paradise and water them from what I have and nothing should go missing from it.’ He will most certainly have seventy-two wives from the wide-eyed maidens of Paradise, the couch of only one of whom is as wide as a square mile on earth.” Musnasd Ahmad hanbal
Also is this Hadith authenic
Hatib ibn Abi Balta`a said, Allah be well-pleased with him: I heard the Messenger of Allah say, upon him blessings and peace: “The believer in Paradise shall be married off to seventy-two women, seventy women of the hereafter and two women of the women of this world
Narrated by Ibn al-Sakan in Maʿrifat al-Sahaba and Ibn ʿAsakir in Tarikh Dimashq
So are the authentic
